# How does one connect a wireless mouse to a computer?

Tags: wireless-mouse

I usually use mouses with wires, but a friend has a wireless mouse, happens to be a Microsoft mobile mouse 2000 but no doubt many are like this.

I'm not sure what it connects to though.

I am not looking at it at the moment.

I imagine it connects to some base, and then the base connects via USB, though the only base I saw was made by Belkin and was a 4 port hub, with a red light so it may have communicated with the mouse but I doubt it.

There's the mouse and there's the computer, there's a usb base. I can't see exactly what  the mouse is transmitting to.

Comment: Perhaps a check at Microsoft's hardware site would help.

Comment: @DragonLord I think it's not too localized now, but was is it now that it's not too localized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dongle stored in a slot on the bottom of the mouse. Plug the dongle into a USB port.